# caching images on browser

Tags: javascript, html, caching

I'm running page performance tools in firebug and I keep getting the suggestion to cache images? I thought browsers cached images by default. How do you cache images?

Comment: you tagged javascript. I don't think JS is the right tool for the job here. If you're best off to do it in your web server IIS/Apache. What are you using?

Comment: They do cache images. It's just firebug, you are in dev mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I cache in IIS7

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="90.00:00:00" />
        <remove fileExtension=".js" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".js" mimeType="text/javascript" />
    </staticContent>
    <caching>
        <profiles>
            <add extension=".png" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".jpeg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".jpg" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".css" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
            <add extension=".js" policy="CacheUntilChange" kernelCachePolicy="CacheUntilChange" duration="00:00:30" />
        </profiles>
    </caching>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

it's just suggestion;
browser will cache images by default,don't worry!

Comment: While this is true, in order to reduce load, you're better off to tell the browser how long to cache it. Otherwise you could potentially be sending redundant data over the wire for no reason.